# Possible workaround for async negedge reset?

Tags: reset, chisel

I'd like to have a register with async reset signal, like following:

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
begin
    if(!rst_n)
        out <= 1'b0
    else
        out <= in
end
```

I have tried class `AsyncReset()` and `withReset()`. However, the generated code uses a posedge reset and the variable of `AsyncReset()` does not accept `!`.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Did you try without the negedge keyword? You can act on any rst_n change, not focusing on any edge... (or at keast in verilog/vhdl you can)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you cannot invert the `AsyncReset` type directly (generally applying logic to an AsyncReset is bad because it can glitch), you can cast to a Bool and back:

```scala
  val reset_n = (!reset.asBool).asAsyncReset
  val reg = withReset(reset_n)(RegInit(0.U(8.W)))
```

Runnable example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ERy0qHt2Q3OvWIsp9qiiNg

Answer (score 2):

I thought Jack's quick comment about avoiding glitches deserved a longer explanation.

Using an asynchronous reset creates a second timing arc in the design, from the reset to the end flop.  The reset signal can be asserted at any time but needs to be de-asserted synchronous to the clock otherwise the flop can become metastable.

A common technique to do this is to use a reset synchronizer.
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hutch31/EPozcu39QBOmaB5So6fyeA/13

The synchronizer shown in the above code is coded directly in Verilog as I do not know a way to keep the FIRRTL optimizer from pruning through constant optimization.  The logic downstream of the reset sync can be either sync or async reset.

Comment: Thanks for adding this additional context, it is important to understand that there are good reasons for disallowing logic on Clock and AsyncReset signals, although I grant maybe we should allow inversion since to my understanding that's safe.

Comment: Inversion of an async reset should be safe, but yes neither clock or async reset nets should normally have logic on them because they are handled specially by PNR tools. Much of the reason for moving to synchronous reset is that it removes the need to treat reset as a "special" net.