# How to generate negedge reset verilog in chisel3.3

Tags: chisel

We are working on an IC project with some back-end team doing placement & routing.
Currently the verilog code generated from chisel3.3 is able to do async reset on posedge.
But the backend team **requires negedge reset** due to foundry technology.
The answer 2 to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229422/possible-workaround-for-async-negedge-reset) generates a reversed resetn signal, but still with posedge.
Is there a switch to set so that the generated verilog can be like this?

```
  always @(posedge clock or negedge reset) begin
    if (!reset) begin
      _T_1 <= 4'h0;
    end else begin
      _T_1 <= io_d;
    end
  end
```